# Error with subtraction with variables

Tags: python

I keep getting this error,

```
       line 37, in <module>
    ahealth = ahealth - attackdmg
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

It was for this line of code.

```
if playerab == ('Attack'):
        attackdmg = randint(2,4)
        pcrit = randint(1,4)
        sleep(1)
        if  pcrit == randint(1,4):
            attackdmg = attackdmg * (2,5)
            print('CRIT!')
        print('You decide to attack the Orc.')
        sleep(1)
        ahealth = ahealth - attackdmg
        print('You hit the orc for', (attackdmg))
        sleep(1)
        print('The Orc has', (ahealth), ('health remaining.'))
        print
        orcturn = True
        playerturn = False
```

I don't understand what is going on here, all of these variables are numbers.

Thanks :)

Comment: when you do `attackdmg = attackdmg * (2,5)`, it is returning a tuple of `(2,5)` repeated `attackdmg` times

Comment: What did you want that line to do? Multiply by 2.5? Multiply by a random number from 2 to 5? Something different?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line `attackdmg = attackdmg * (2,5)` where you are multiplying an integer by the tuple `(2,5)`.

I don't know what you were trying to do there, but that line of code works like this: if `attackdmg = 1`, you get `(2,5)`, if `attackdmg = 2`, you get `(2,5,2,5)`, and so on.

As you are new to python, it may be useful to explain what a tuple is. A tuple is a type of list that is immutable. It can contain one or more values. To get an item from a tuple, simply use `tup[index]` where 'tup' is the tuple and 'index' is the index of the value you want to return.

Answer (score 0):

The line `attackdmg = attackdmg * (2,5)` should presumably be `attackdmg = attackdmg * 2.5`.

Answer (score 0):

I just missed randint before the (2,5). So it was a tuple instead.